# Compose Microsoft Teams message from configurable tab

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a Microsoft Teams configurable tab with Angular and the [Microsoft Teams Javascript library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/teams-js). From this tab I would like to be able to click a button which will "pre-compose" a message in the chat of the channel/chat of where the configurable tab is installed. So when the button is clicked, Teams should navigate to the "Posts" tab of the channel/chat and fill in the text/url/string in the chat and let the user decide to press enter to send it.

I've read the documentation but I cannot conclude that this is possible. I've looked at creating a task module but this only seems to be able to open dialogs to get the user to fill in data and call a service. The bot documentation also seems to mention filling the compose box of the chat but the documentation is not very clear in specifying how the bot should be called from e.g. tabs.

Comment: I think this -might- be possible, but I'm not totally sure - would have to check around a bit. Our of interest, why can't you just do a normal "compose box" message extension (e.g. like the "Wiki" tool out of the box), instead of having the interaction take place in a tab?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but the tab is quite complex. "click a button" is actually a more complex interaction which involves filters and queries in looking for the right content to share. Which would not be a great user experience from within a message extension.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Did you find anything?

Comment: Hi @dylanvdb, we have an option for [deeplink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat) to chat not for channel from configurable tab. Could you please check this document.

Comment: @Jagadeesh-MSFT Thank you for the reply, but that does not seem to align with our complete use case, this would work for pre-composing a message to members of a "chat", but we need this functionality for channels as well.

Answer (score 0):

was able to deep link to group chat Tab by setting contextType property. Could you Please try deeplinking to group chat with the below syntax:
[https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity//?context={"chatId"](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity//?context=%7B%22chatId%22): "","contextType":"chat"}

Comment: Thank you Jagadeesh, but that would not allow me to specify a card to display within the compose box if I'm not mistaken? I am able to do this from a message extension through a task module but I am starting to think that it is not possible from a configurable tab, is this correct?

Comment: Hi @dylanvdb, currently it is not possible to send messages from configurable tab to compose box area.

Comment: Hi Jagadeesh, thank you for the reply. Do you know if this is on the roadmap/a planned feature of the SDK?